# 'uploads' and 'jpg' amongst my 10 top keywords in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console

Amongst my 10 top keywords in Google WebMaster Tools (Search Console) I have noticed that 'uploads' and 'jpg' show up in 4th and 5th position. This does not make sense to me although I suspect the reason is because I use wordpress and my photos are all located at the following URL:

`http://www.monsitecom/wp-content/uploads/**/*.jpg`

Would that affect my SEO ? And can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

What Google selects as the keywords for your site depends on what it assesses as the most appropriate keywords. The fact that `uploads` and `jpg` are showing up rated so highly as your sites keywords would indicate to me that your site is lacking keyword appropriate valuable content. SEO is very much an art form and getting it right takes a lot of time, patience, and most importantly experimentation. The only thing you can do to change this is to update existing pages and add new pages with valuable context appropriate content with natural keyword selection. In other words make the keywords a natural part of the sentences within the page, don't simply add them as a list.

If you keep up this process and maintain the evolution of your site with appropriate content then you should see better value keywords in your top 10 list.

Comment: well,thanks for the answer. My question is almost a year old. By now, all these 'uploads' and 'jpg' keywords have been long gone and replaced with proper keywords. It was more a glitch of the webmaster tools I think.